# Provide "Open File" command from Visual Studio Code Source Control pane context menu

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

In Visual Studio Code, when I'm using Git source control for a project, I can right-click on a file in source control view and select "Open File" to look at the file as if I had simply opened it from the Explorer pane. How do I implement a similar context menu and command for my own SCM extension? I have it working to the point where files are listed and I can select one to show differences, or select inline command icons to show differences between versions selected in different ways. But I can't figure out how to add a context menu or a command to simply open one of these files instead of a comparison.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the context menu, a command and a context menu item can be specified in the package.json file. In the `contributes` block's `commands` array, add a command like:

```json
{
    "command": "accurev.openFile",
    "category": "AccuRev",
    "title": "Open file"
}
```

Then refer to the command from a context menu item defined in, for example, the `scm/resourceState/context` array of the `menus` block:

```json
{
    "command": "accurev.openFile",
    "when": "scmProvider == accurev"
}
```

Finally, register a command handler for the new command that uses Visual Studio Code's built-in `open` command. This can be done in the code that runs during the extension's initial `activate` function:

```ts
globalState.disposables.push(vscode.commands.registerCommand('accurev.openFile', async (file: AccuRevFile) => {
    try {
        await vscode.commands.executeCommand('vscode.open', file.resourceUri);
    }
    catch(err) {
        if (globalState) {
            globalState.channel.appendLine(err);
        }
    }
}));
```

In this example `globalState` is just a variable that keeps track of some global variables in the extension, including the list of disposable objects that will be cleaned up with the extension shuts down, and the channel where log text is written for the extension.